# Error Handler Not working in Function VBA Access 2013

Tags: ms-access, vba

So I have a function that allows the user to email an updated picture for an asset which works fine and good except if the user closes the email before sending.  I have an error handler set up but it doesn't seem to capture the error.  Here is my function code:

```
Function Email()
Globals.Logging "Opened Email for updating picture"
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler:
Dim strTagNumber As String
strTagNumber = Me.txtTagNumber.Value

Dim varName As Variant
Dim varCC As Variant
Dim varSubject As Variant
Dim varBody As Variant

varName = "myAnon@email.test"
varCC = ""
varSubject = "Updated Picture for Asset Number " & strTagNumber
varBody = "Sent by MS Access"

DoCmd.SendObject , , , varName, varCC, , varSubject, varBody, True, False
Globals.Logging "Sent Email"

Cleanup:
  varName = Nothing
  varCC = Nothing
  varSubject = Nothing
  varBody = Nothing
  Exit Function

ErrorHandler:
  Select Case Err.Number
    Case 2501
      MsgBox "Email message was Cancelled."
      Globals.Logging "Canceled Email"
    Case Else
      MsgBox Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
      Globals.Logging "Email Error " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
  End Select
  Resume Cleanup
End Function
```

Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: if you take this out - `On Error GoTo ErrorHandler:` which line does it stop on?

Comment: Is there even an error to catch?  BTW the first thing you do in CleanUp is `Exit Function`?

Comment: It only throws the error if the user closes the email before sending which is what the error handler is designed to handle.  The error is Run-time Error '2501' "The SendObject action was canceled".

Comment: Review https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/c391306c-15d6-4970-bb9f-4fa1d74f7dec/error-handling-if-docmdsendobject-is-cancelled?forum=accessdev

Comment: I have almost the exact code as in the thread you suggested that I review.  I put a stop on the error handler and it is never going there.  It seems the On Error is not trapping the error.

Comment: How is the function being called? Is there an error handler on that parent method?

Comment: What do you mean by it "doesn't _seem_ to capture the error" and then later "it throws the error"?  Do you mean it shows the pop-up message but then continues with the VBA code without ever going to the ErrorHandler?  Sorry to be picky about words, but to me "throwing the error" actually means it causes the error handling code to execute (not just showing a pop-up).

Comment: No I mean that I get a run-time error 2501 from VBA with options to end or debug which I don't want the user to see.

Comment: Parfait, it is called in the double click event for the OLE object in the form by name

Comment: Ok I figured it out, I had the options in the vba editor set to break on all errors.  I changed it to break on unhandled errors and the error handler works now.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

As described in [online documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/access-vba/articles/docmd-sendobject-method-access?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), DoCmd.SendObjects

> ... uses the Mail Applications Programming Interface (MAPI)

In other words, Access (or Excel) does not actually have its own email capability.  It is dependent upon a properly installed and configured MAPI email client.  Unless you have purposefully installed and setup another default email client on Windows, the default is likely Outlook if you have it installed with MS Office.  Windows email clients have changed with the many version of Windows, but the default might also be a simple Windows email client.

It is very likely that the MAPI client could be showing the error message, then not actually throwing/raising the error before it returns program flow back to the VBA module which initiated the call.

I recall being aware at some point of an Outlook setting that dictated certain behavior for MAPI and/or COM Automation interfaces, whether it showed errors or not.  I usually would not throw out such wishy-washy info on Stack Overflow before verifying, but from what I see of the discussion around this issue, nobody really addresses this aspect of SendObjects.

Besides using Automation to send email via Outlook as other have suggested, you could inspect the Windows default email client settings.  Perhaps test another email client to see if you get different results.

Answer (score 0):

Tested on Access 2016. The error is captured and I can see the message box saying "Email message was Cancelled.".

Maybe you can try to use Outlook object for sending the email too.

Comment: Hmmm, that is definitely weird since it is still not working for me.